# Adding fonts to JEdit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jedit

I'm trying to add Monaco true type font on JEdit under Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.isnull.com.ar/2010/05/monaco-font-unbuntu.html

Comment: Thanks, my superiors will be most pleased.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote http://www.isnull.com.ar/2010/05/monaco-font-unbuntu.html

Nope, this instruction installs the font for Linux, but not necessarily makes it visible to Jedit.